# I want to make a new dictionary with key as call_id and value as a list of time between start_time and end_time

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

[image: 1]

I want to create a dictionary with key as call_id and value a list of range(start_time, end_time)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
df[['call_id', 'start_time', 'end_time']].set_index('call_id').T.to_dict('list')
```